# Set data from database to generated popup window in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have created a popup window in cakephp.

`<div id="pop_box">
    <span id="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>This is the Popup Box</h2>
    <span id="selected_content"></span>
</div>`

Now I want to set data to this popup window by getting data from database(MySql). Normally we are getting data from database for a new page using functions in controller. Here it is not a new page. How can I do this with that popup window?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are doing here if you want help. How does your popup work? Is it called via AJAX? There should be little difference with setting the data for the view from what you normally would do. Add more details/code to your question. Also it is always worth stating the version of CakePHP being used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a view for your controller action. the view file name has to be conventionally named i.e underscored version of the cooresponding  controller action e.g if you have action named viewArticle the view file w'd be view_article.ctp

```
public function viewArticle(){

        $data = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all',$conditions);

       // here set your data to view
       $this->set(compact('data'));
   }
```

now create the view file (view_article.ctp)and paste your popup window code and your data  from controller sh'd be readily accessible with $data

PS: the data to use with js popup window was preloaded. if you need your popup to get its data asynchronously then checkout  cakephp + ajax usage they sh'd be couple them here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I got all the data into array at once when create the page. Then I show the relevant data on my popup window. I know this may not be the optimal solution. But for this situation this was OK.

Comment: that's the standard way to do it. please accept my answer if it helped you.